# Why can't I log a user out of facebook in an AIR desktop application?

Tags: flash, facebook, air

I'm building an AIR desktop app with facebook support using Adobe Flash builder. So far it's working alright, except for one detail, once a user logs in, that session stays open, even if the logout button is pressed. My logout code look like so:

```
                protected function logout():void {
                   FacebookDesktop.logout(handleLogout, APP_ORIGIN);
                }
```

I set APP_ORIGIN to "http://www.facebook.com". I checked Adobe's documentation and they say:    appOrigin:String (default = null) — (Optional) The site url specified for your app. Required for clearing html window cookie. But I don't know what that means, what is the 'site url specified by my app'? Where do I get it? Sorry if this is a noob question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out, what I did was define my app origin as localhost and now it works.

Comment: I'm having problems with the logout too, why do I have to supply APP_OGIRIN?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but if you don't the session cookie will not be cleaned and the user will not be logged out. The way I solved it (for desktop) was using this app origin:

Answer (score 3):

After trying 20 different workarounds, the only solution that worked for me is:
http://nekyouto-tech.blogspot.de/2012/09/fb-adobe-air-logout-bug.html

```
var uri:String = APP_ORIGIN;
var params:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
params.next = uri;
params.access_token = FacebookDesktop.getSession().accessToken;
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://www.facebook.com/logout.php");
req.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
req.data = params;
var netLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
netLoader.load(req);
FacebookDesktop.logout(handleLogout, APP_ORIGIN);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me

```
    public function facebookLogout():void {
        if (FacebookDesktop.getSession() != null) {
            var uri:String = "http://www.facebook.com/";
            var params:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
            params.next = uri;
            params.access_token = FacebookDesktop.getSession().accessToken;
            var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://www.facebook.com/logout.php");
            req.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
            req.data = params;
            var netLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            netLoader.load(req);
            FacebookDesktop.logout(handleLogout, uri);      
        }
    }
```